# Layout Problem between Labels Dot Language Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot, family-tree

I am having issues on keeping Marge near Homer and Herb near Lucia to avoid this above-line (check the image). Basicly i need to keep married couples together and push aside brothers to fix the lines from mixing.
Here is my source code:

```
digraph G {
  edge [dir=none];
  node [shape=box];
  graph [splines=ortho];

  "Abraham"   [shape=box, regular=0, color="blue", style="filled" fillcolor="lightblue"] ;
  "Mona"      [shape=box, regular=0, color="red", style="filled" fillcolor="pink"] ;
  a1 [shape=diamond,label="",height=0.25,width=0.25];
  {rank=same; Abraham -> a1 -> Mona};
  "Herb"      [shape=box, regular=0, color="blue", style="filled" fillcolor="lightblue"] ;
  "Lucia"     [shape=box, regular=0, color="red", style="filled"fontcolor="", fillcolor="pink"] ;
  "Homer"     [shape=box, regular=0, color="blue",fontcolor="blue", style="bold, filled" fillcolor="lightblue"] ;
  "Marge"     [shape=box, regular=0, color="red", style="bold,filled"fontcolor="red", fillcolor="pink"] ;
  p2 [shape=diamond,label="",style="",height=0.25,width=0.25];
  {rank=same; Herb -> p2 -> Lucia };
  {rank=same; Herb; Homer}
  b1 [shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
  b2 [shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
  b3 [shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
{rank=same; b1 -> b2 -> b3};
  a1 -> b2;
  b1 -> Herb;
  b3 -> Homer;
  "Gendry"      [shape=box, regular=0, color="blue", style="filled" fillcolor="lightblue"] ;
  Herb -> Gendry;
  p2 -> c2;
  c1 -> Bob;
  c3-> John;
  {rank=same;  c1 -> c2 -> c3}
   c1 [shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
  "Bob"      [shape=box, regular=0, color="blue", style="filled" fillcolor="lightblue"] ;
  c2 [shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
  "John"      [shape=box, regular=0, color="blue", style="filled" fillcolor="lightblue"] ;
  c3 [shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
   
  p1 [shape=diamond,label="",style="bold",height=0.25,width=0.25];
  {rank=same; Homer -> p1 -> Marge};
  {rank=same; Bob; John; Gendry}
}
```

[family-tree-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8MWs.png)

Comment: Hello! I'm afraid your question is difficult to answer as is so in order to get more (useful) answers, I suggest a few changes. The title of the question is not actually related to your problem (your problem has to do with lay-out and is not specific to family trees). Also, "dot" is a language that many people are not going to be aware about so please make sure it's clear you are asking a question about a language called "dot". Finally, your example is fairly complex. Is there any way you can simplify to make it easier to understand?

Comment: Thanks alot for your suggestions. I tried following some of them but the example is complex because if I remove some of the content the alignment is kind of correct. To start noticing issues there must be 3 generations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want should be straight-forward using **dot**, but as you found, it is impressively difficult.  Two techniques that should get you there are adding **weight** attributes to edges to keep nodes close to each other and/or using **clusters** to explicitly group the couples close.  Using **clusters** does keep the couples together, but it resulted in ugly edges.  Adding weights helped to get the invisible nodes placed "correctly" and resulted in nicer-looking edges.

```
digraph G {
  edge [dir=none];
  node [shape=box];
  graph [splines=ortho];

  subgraph cluster1{
      peripheries=0
  "Abraham"   [shape=box, regular=0, color="blue", style="filled" fillcolor="lightblue"] ;
  "Mona"      [shape=box, regular=0, color="red", style="filled" fillcolor="pink"] ;
  a1 [shape=diamond,label="",height=0.25,width=0.25];
  {rank=same; Abraham -> a1 -> Mona};
  }

  subgraph cluster3{
  peripheries=0
  "Homer"     [shape=box, regular=0, color="blue",fontcolor="blue", style="bold, filled" fillcolor="lightblue"] ;
  "Marge"     [shape=box, regular=0, color="red", style="bold,filled"fontcolor="red", fillcolor="pink"] ;
  {rank=same; Homer -> p1 -> Marge};
  p1 [shape=diamond,label="",style="bold",height=0.25,width=0.25];
  }
  subgraph cluster2{
      peripheries=0
  "Herb"      [shape=box, regular=0, color="blue", style="filled" fillcolor="lightblue"] ;
  "Lucia"     [shape=box, regular=0, color="red", style="filled"fontcolor="", fillcolor="pink"] ;
  {rank=same; Herb -> p2 -> Lucia };
  p2 [shape=diamond,label="",style="",height=0.25,width=0.25];
  }

  b1 [shape=point style=invis width=0 label=""]  //,height=0.01,width=0.01];
  b2 [shape=point style=invis width=0 label=""]  //,height=0.01,width=0.01];
  b3 [shape=point style=invis width=0 label=""]  //,height=0.01,width=0.01];
  {rank=same; weight=0   b1 -> b2 -> b3};
  {
  a1 -> b2;
  b1 -> Herb  [weight=9]
  b3 -> Homer [weight=9]
  }

  "Gendry"      [shape=box, regular=0, color="blue", style="filled" fillcolor="lightblue"] ;

  {rank=same; weight=0  c1 -> c2 -> c3}
   c1 [shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
  "Bob"      [shape=box, regular=0, color="blue", style="filled" fillcolor="lightblue"] ;
  c2 [shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
  "John"      [shape=box, regular=0, color="blue", style="filled" fillcolor="lightblue"] ;
  c3 [shape=circle,label="",height=0.01,width=0.01];
   
  Herb -> Gendry;
  p2 -> c2 weight=99;
  c1 -> Bob weight=99;
  c3-> John weight=99;
  {rank=same; Bob; John; Gendry}
}
```

Produces this (not great, but better):
[image]

Comment: It seems to fix my issue. I'll now try to work on a way to fix the weird line space bellow the diamond. Thanks alot.